# Why does Russia reject China's peace proposal?

Tags: russian-federation, china, ukraine

> On 24 February 2023, China issued a twelve-point peace plan outline,
> calling for a cease fire and peace talks. The same day, Zelenskyy
> indicated he was willing to consider aspects of the proposal,
> while Russia's foreign ministry stated that it welcomed the Chinese
> proposal. Zelenskyy stated that he planned to meet Xi because it
> would be useful to both countries and global security. However,
> Vladimir Putin's spokesperson Dmitry Peskov rejected the Chinese peace
> proposal, saying that "for now, we don't see any of the conditions
> that are needed to bring this whole story towards peace."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China_during_the_Russo-Ukrainian_War#Peace_proposal

Russia's spokesperson said Russia rejected the peace proposal because the conditions are not there to bring this whole thing to an end. What are the conditions he's referring to and why exactly Russia doesn't consider the peace proposal fair?

Comment: The Chinese peace plan is very vague and the Ukrainian or Russian reactions to also very vague. Maybe it's a non-issue, not a real plan, just some words, loosely related to what might pass as a partly plan.

Comment: FWIW, there is the [full text](https://english.news.cn/20230224/f6bf935389394eb0988023481ab26af4/c.html) of China's plan.  I am also curious on downvotes, any particular objection to the phrasing of the question?  Although other Russian responses about this were phrased differently and mostly blamed Ukraine/West for not being ready to talk peace rather than anything with the China plan.

Comment: What would be expected to happen if Russia "accepted" the Chinese plan? What would happen then?

Comment: It is not clear from the OP whether Russia has actually *rejected* the peace proposal or whether it is the interpretation by the author of the Wikipedia article. Peskov's diplomatic language in the [article cited by Wikipedia](https://www.themoscowtimes.com/2023/02/27/kremlin-on-china-plan-says-no-conditions-for-peace-at-the-moment-in-ukraine-a80345) is open to interpretations.

Comment: @njkz2 Russia would move the army from all occupied territories, including Crimea, returning these territories to Ukraine. For that, Ukraine makes discounts like no Nato and whatever else has been the reason for invasion. Zelenskiy is ready to talk on these terms, see https://www.theguardian.com/world/live/2023/mar/28/russia-ukraine-war-live-news-updates-multiple-russian-drones-shot-down-over-kyiv-blasts-attack?page=with:block-6422e8338f08fa1b55ea239f#block-6422e8338f08fa1b55ea239f for instance

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Russia does not want to move out of the annexed territories of Ukraine. And the 12 item proposal by China lists the **respect of all countries' territorial sovereignty** as the first item, read it at [my.china-embassy.gov.cn](http://my.china-embassy.gov.cn/eng/zgxw/202302/t20230224_11030881.htm). Hence Russia is not willing to accept this peace proposal.

It looks like there was some playing around, kind of like maybe Ukraine is somehow not a country or the annexed territories are somehow now rightfully part of Russia, but China does not officially recognize either.

Comment: To be fair, the 2nd and 3rd items are much more on the pro-Russia side.  #2 because it basically keeps NATO support out and #3 because a ceasefire now would benefit Russia by freezing the conflict in place.  Everyone can interpret this plan pretty much as they see fit, due to its vagueness.   Rather than an outright dismissal, I think the initial Russian was much more their standard-issue "We're ready to talk.  But the West isn't!".  Which actually is a bit of a flaw in the way the question was asked, implying more rejection than there was.  Still, a valid enough Q overall.

Comment: So basically the same reason every pro-Russia westerner calling for peace negotiations has been in the wrong for a long time, only now it's so blatantly obvious even they will have a hard time coming up with an excuse for why it's actually Ukraine's fault.

Comment: You're saying the reason Russia rejected the plan is because they believe they aren't respecting Ukraine's territorial sovereignty?

Comment: @Hasse1987 the opposite. The plan asks for the respect of territorial sovereignty, but Russia doesn't want to leave occupied territories, so it doesn't want to respect Ukraine's territorial sovereignty.

Comment: @bracco23: That's not the opposite, it sidesteps the point.  Hasse1987's comment draws attention to the mismatch between what Russia says is Ukraine's sovereign territory and what the rest of the world thinks.

Answer (score 20):

TLDR: China's peace plan is so vague that Putin can easily [agree](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-65030929) to "most" of it

> China's plan, published last month, does not explicitly call for Russia to leave Ukraine.
>
> [...] it calls for peace talks and respect for national sovereignty, without specific proposals.
>
> But Ukraine has insisted on Russia withdrawing from its territory as a condition for any talks - and there is no sign that Russia is ready to do that.
>
> [...] In a joint news conference after talks with Mr Xi ended, Mr Putin said: "Many provisions of the Chinese peace plan can be taken as the basis for settling of the conflict in Ukraine, whenever the West and Kyiv are ready for it."

He didn't exactly say what provisions he likes and which he doesn't in China's plan, but just blamed Ukraine for not being "ready". I.e.: [vague plan](https://thediplomat.com/2023/03/chinas-plan-for-ukraine-is-no-plan-at-all/), vague endorsement. The only thing clear in all of this diplomacy spectacle is Russia laying the blame on Ukraine and the West. Nothing new under the sun.

From an earlier [piece](https://www.themoscowtimes.com/2023/02/27/kremlin-on-china-plan-says-no-conditions-for-peace-at-the-moment-in-ukraine-a80345), which doesn't have direct quotes on this:

> The Russian Foreign Ministry on Friday thanked Chinese efforts but said that any settlement of the conflict needed to recognize Russia's control over four Ukrainian regions.

I managed to find a more extensive coverage of [that](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/russia-welcomes-china-peace-plan-says-it-is-open-talks-2023-02-24/):

> "We appreciate the sincere desire of our Chinese friends to contribute to resolving the conflict in Ukraine by peaceful means... We share the views of Beijing," Foreign Ministry spokeswoman Maria Zakharova said in a statement.
>
> "With regard to the Ukraine crisis, Russia is open to achieving the goals of the special military operation by political and diplomatic means," Zakharova said.
>
> However, this would also mean recognising "new territorital realities" in Ukraine, Zakharova said, referring to Russia's unilateral annexation of four Ukrainian regions - Donetsk, Lukhansk, Kherson and Zaporizhzhia - as well as of Crimea.

And since that's not explicit in China's plan... it's a case of "we 'like' your plan, but we like ours better".

---

BTW/aside: this style of Chinese plan (rather vague talking points) are not really new. Does anyone remember China's [2017 plan](https://thediplomat.com/2017/08/china-has-a-new-middle-east-peace-plan/) for peace between Israel and the Palestinians? That too was described by some Israeli academic as a "façade of diplomatic activism while adhering to existing policies of minimal involvement [...] all share three characteristics: they do not contain innovative ideas; they do not reflect Chinese willingness to invest significant resources in the resolution of these conflicts; and no one has taken them seriously." That's quite unlike the [later] Iran-Saudi talks that China *was* willing to host.

Comment: But China's plan does not explicitly call for Russia to leave Ukraine.

Comment: @convert: precisely, so where is the "but"? It's a vague plan.

Comment: So why should Russia reject it then?

Comment: @convert: Well, I didn't write that they rejected it. I wrote it's not a full endorsement. So glass half empty or half full? It's down to a certain level of sophistry. If I take some of your territory, but I say that it's mine now, I'm "respecting" your territorial integrity (minus what I just took)... that's the only way to claim the Russian endorsement +their "however" is not a partial rejection of principle #1 from the Chinese plan.

Answer (score 5):

> What are the conditions he's referring to and why exactly Russia doesn't consider the peace proposal fair?

It's hard to say with utter certainty, as Russia is not fond of speaking clearly, but Russia's official position is that the Kherson, Zaporizhzhia, Donetsk, and Luhansk oblasts are Russian territory, and thus the portions of those territories that are held by Ukrainian forces are occupied territory. Obviously, Ukraine isn't going to withdraw from this territory in exchange for a peace treaty, so any peace treaty that Russia would sign at this point would, according to the Russian position, be ceding Russian territory, which is not acceptable terms. It's clear that Russia will not agree to any peace treaty until they either capture this remaining territory or it become manifestly clear that they will not be able to do so. Or Putin is overthrown,

Comment: More options surely exist - Russia and Ukraine may sign some kind of ceasefire or even peace treaty with some borders which do not depict either side's total victory conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Russia has not rejected the plan, as can be seen from a [statement by Putin](https://officelife.media/news/41653-putin-podderzhal-mirnyy-plan-kitaya-po-ukraine-no-est-nyuans/):

> **Putin supported China's peace plan for Ukraine, but there is a nuance**
>
> The Presidents of Russia and China made a joint statement following Xi
> Jinping's visit to Moscow. Vladimir Putin, among other things, touched
> upon the peaceful settlement of the armed conflict between Russia and
> Ukraine.
>
> The Russian leader said that China's peace plan "can be taken as a
> basis for a peaceful settlement when the West and Kiev are ready for
> it. But so far we have not observed such readiness on their part."
>
> In turn, Xi Jinping said that China "adheres to an objective position,
> supports the resumption of negotiations."
>
> The Presidents of Russia and China have also announced economic
> agreements. In particular, Russia promised to continue supplying oil
> and gas to China, including completing the Power of Siberia—2 gas
> pipeline project.
>
> In addition, the statement following the visit said that "the Russian
> side confirms its commitment to the one China principle, recognizes
> that Taiwan is an integral part of the PRC, opposes Taiwan's
> independence in any form, firmly supports the actions of the Chinese
> side to protect its state sovereignty and territorial integrity."

Also the quote by Peskov was taken out of context by the Wikipedia article. As can be read in that article, nothing was said about rejecting the plan. [Here is the complete statement:](https://www.themoscowtimes.com/2023/02/27/kremlin-on-china-plan-says-no-conditions-for-peace-at-the-moment-in-ukraine-a80345)

> "We paid a lot of attention to our Chinese friends' plan," Kremlin spokesman Dmitry Peskov said on Monday, adding that: "for now, we don't see any of the conditions that are needed to bring this whole story towards peace."

Comment: From what I am seeing it seems that the statement rejecting the idea came first and the statement you quoted was a recent on that came later.

Comment: @Joe W Even if the statement by Putin came later it still shows that Russia has not rejected the plan.

Comment: Translation: we "support" your peace plan, but we really support ours (more). And we still blame Ukraine for everything. Anyhow, the last two paras in the quote seem unrelated.

Comment: @Fizz But the main point is that Russia has not rejected the plan.

Comment: @Joe W Also the article, where the quote comes from says nothing about rejecting the plan.

Comment: "But there is a nuance" has a **very** special (and hilarious) meaning in Russian. See, for example: [Но есть один нюанс — Неолурк](https://neolurk.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE_%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD_%D0%BD%D1%8E%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81), or google: *"Но есть один нюанс"*.

Comment: I am going to agree with this.  Russia has not rejected the plan, as much as stuck to their previous line that they are 200% ready to talk peace but the West/Ukraine is not willing to do so.  Nothing wrong whatsoever with this answer.  This avoids them having to annoy Xi, which is probably rule #1, rule #2 and rule #3 of Kremlin diplomacy at this point.

Comment: That isn't the point but removing the need for people to click through your link and try and guess at what in the link they are supposed to be seeing

Comment: In short, the precondition is that Ukraine stops resisting.

Answer (score -8):

Putin may like the Chinese plan, but he may not like the postive PR that China will get due to it. If Chinese mediation is successful, the press will say China has become Russia's equal. While Putin and XI are pragmatic and Russian - Chinese relationship have peaked at the moment, it is still an uneasy alliance. Nevertheless, from the perspective of international diplomacy, Ukraine is the one who is at fault as their diplomatic corps hasn't behaved professionally with the Chinese, while Putin has been smarter.

Seeing that Zelensky hasn't even met the Chinese premiere to discuss the so called "chinese peace plan", while Putin just met and discussed it with the Chinese, it is easy to see why the Russians are dismissive of the Chinese peace proposal - if the Ukranians don't consider the proposal (or China) seriously and aren't even willing to talk about it, what's the point? Unless somebody is willing to talk, even through a third-party, where's the conducive conditions for diplomacy to happen?

When the Chinese presented their plan, it was met with immediate criticism by the Ukranians:

> Advisor to the Head of the Presidential Office Mykhailo Podoliak voiced Ukraine’s arguments against China's "peace plan." According to him, it means a defeat for Ukraine and freezing of the war ... According to him “Chinese peace plan” contains points that contradict each other. China does not seek to end Russia's war against Ukraine in peace. Instead, it may prolong the war and lead to Ukraine's defeat. - [*Presidential Office Representative Explains Why Kyiv Is Against China's "Peace Plan"*](https://web.archive.org/web/20230301182747/https://tsn.ua/en/ato/presidential-office-representative-explains-why-kyiv-is-against-china-s-peace-plan-2275624.html)

Zelensky toned it down immediately and publicly claimed that he was willing to discuss it. But other Ukrainians continue shooting their mouths and criticising the plan **publicly**:

> *"China is absolutely not neutral,"* said Merezhko, who represents Zelensky's Servant of the People party and chairs the parliament's foreign affairs committee. *"It conducts military exercises with Russia. It openly blames the West and NATO, not the actual aggressor. Russia and China are the core of a coalition waging hybrid war against democracy and undermining the rules-based order."*
>
> ... Bohdan Yaremenko, also a member of the parliament's foreign affairs committee, said that expectations were already low in Kyiv. *"No one was anticipating anything of the Chinese,"* he told Newsweek. *"For a global superpower to take a year's worth of time thinking about the situation and then to deliver what was delivered is very tragic."* - ['No Hope': Ukraine Lawmakers Dismiss China Peace Talk After Putin-Xi Meet](https://www.newsweek.com/xi-jinping-vladimir-putin-china-russia-ukraine-war-peace-1789564).

This is amatuerish diplomacy as it even disregards one of the golden rule of diplomacy and etiquette - *"If you don't have anything nice to say about somebody then just shut up"*. (Ukrainian diplomacy has been almost like social media campaign, with knee-jerk reactions attacking anyone who says something the Ukranians don't like or don't want to accept).

At the same time, Ukraine has been claiming that China or Xi has been "snubbing" them and ignoring their "invitation". There are two things to note here:

1. Obviously when you publicly criticise a country or its leaders, should anyone be surprised that they are being cold-shouldered? (Especially when Asians are very sensitive to public criticism).
2. Ukraine is the smaller power in the world order. Ukraine is the one who needs a diplomatic solution to this war. It is not only stupid, but insulting to China, to send "invitations" to Chinese leader asking *them* to come down to Ukriane to meet Zelensky, when he should be the one seeking a meeting with Chinese leadership, and even be willing to meet junior leaders to show his willingness to diplomacy (even if it may not be fruitful).

It's understandable that Zelensky cannot go against the advise of the US, who have been a very strong and supportive ally of Ukraine. But this is problematic for Ukraine as Zelensky isn't directly talking with the Chinese, and instead indirectly letting the west speak for them with China. To the Chinese, this confirms Russian assertions that Ukraine is now a *"puppet of the west"*.

After mediating between the Iranians and the Saudis, the Chinese leadership want to be more on the world stage and be seen as a powerful player. That *need of the Chinese leadership* could have been exploited by Ukraine, even if only for PR value. The Chinese only like to publicise their successes, and not failures, and thus do not like to work under public glare. But Ukrainians either don't grasp this, or the western media isn't deliberately helping them by always publishing anti-Chinese perspective.

Comment: They don't have to meet with someone to consider is seriously.

Comment: Do you have a citation that Ukraine didn't want to meet with Xi? Or other citation that shows they are unwilling to talk to China?

Comment: Nah, Zelensky was unexpectedly receptive to "the plan" going out of his to talk it up after Ukraine's Western backers talked it down.  So that is just plain wrong.  The trouble is that there is not much to "the plan" as it really doesn't say much about who should do what.  So what is there to talk about?  And whatever the merits or not of it, UA and RU have not reached the point where either is willing to make concessions, that much is correct.  But blaming it on UA is wrong.

Comment: Ukrainians have complained that they were not invited https://news.sky.com/story/ukraine-war-china-unveils-12-point-peace-plan-as-it-calls-for-ceasefire-12818707

Comment: And likewise at least one Chinese army official would admit that China is not talking to Ukraine because Ukraine is perceived in China as too close the West (and to Washington in particular). https://time.com/6264512/insiders-perspective-on-chinas-strategy-in-ukraine/

Comment: Looks Zelenskij wants to talk to Xi : https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-64762219

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica It doesn't matter if there wasn't anything of substance in the peace proposal. If a world power makes a diplomatic overture to you, whether seriously or just to feed their leaders ego, you give them respect and talk to them. Even if nothing works out, the other country will remember that you were polite and respectful. (Even the US have now begun acknowledging that the US leadership were wrong in not engaging with the Vietnamese before and during the war, because they assumed they were staunchly in the Russian camp). See my post update for more.

Comment: @Fizz And that is the fault of the Ukranian leadership and diplomacy. See my post update.

Comment: @bharring See my post updates. They deliberately created an unconducive diplomatic environment.

Comment: @sfxedit [Ukraine war: Zelensky wants Xi Jinping meeting following China's peace plan - BBC News](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-64762219)...

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica From the same article: *The Chinese authorities have so far not publicly responded to Mr Zelensky's call for a summit with Mr Xi.* (I have pointed out the reason why). *The Ukrainian leader added that his country had failed to engage sufficiently with countries in Africa and Latin America after many nations in those continents abstained during a UN General Assembly vote on a resolution condemning Russia's invasion.* (Supports my assertion that Ukraine diplomatic efforts have been sup par).

Comment: Ukraine diplomatic efforts are known to be deficient compared to Russia *in Africa*.  That just comes with the territory of being a poor country (9x less GDP than Russia) with no great history of diplomacy in the region.  Has little do with Ukraine-China diplomacy.  Re. the 2 people that shot off their mouth, they are not directly in the diplomatic loop.  Besides UA has plenty of reasons to be disappointed in China (and it probably is a hassle to keep dissenters in line).  Biggest obstacle is likely to be the timing:  peace plan was announced fairly shortly before Xi's Moscow trip.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I don't ascribe this to low GDP. Post-war, the Ukranian leadership has been lulled into a stagnant state on international diplomacy because they let the US + EU do all the work on that front. And ofcourse, trusted them and accepted their advise. But now that the west's enthusiasm is waning, Ukraine's diplomatic effort seem directionless. As for the 2 politician shooting their mouth, it matters a lot because it makes Zelensky looks weak if he can't control what politicians of his party say publicly and in diplomacy everything said by political leaders has an impact.

Comment: @sfxedit Well, Biden couldn't Pelosi's big mouth either.  That's part of being a democracy and separation of powers, innit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144890/discussion-between-sfxedit-and-italian-philosophers-4-monica).

Comment: This would be a good answer but the Russia-PR angle is irrelevant and detracts from the answer. If you must put it it may be better afterward.  Personally I'd delete everything except the two Ukraine official quotes. These speak louder than any musings one may have on the (de)merits of diplomacy.  These two quotes alone say well enough that Ukraine does not want peace on anything but the most maximalist terms